# LGTM python no language data

Tags: python

I use LGTM for code quality analysis.
My LGTM badge recently went from "A+" to "no language data"
[image: my lgtm badge]

You can see it in my [README](https://github.com/MatthewReid854/reliability/blob/master/README.md).

I have no idea how to fix this and the LGTM site doesn't show any record of this error that I could find. I thought that I may need an [lgtm.yml](https://help.semmle.com/lgtm-enterprise/user/help/lgtm.yml-configuration-file.html) file but I have been using LGTM without one for the last few months without seeing this error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: “For a Python project, for example, this may happen if LGTM fails to detect the correct Python version.” (From LGTM site)

Comment: Seems strange that this has only popped up now. I haven't made any major changes. Do you have a proposed solution for me to try? Perhaps I need a lgtm.yml file.

Comment: The most recent build didn't fail. You can see it's status here: https://lgtm.com/projects/g/MatthewReid854/reliability/logs/languages/lang:python

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one with this issue, so perhaps it's on LGTM's side.
https://github.community/t/lgtm-suddenly-code-grades-not-available-for-python/131550

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an LGTM issue that was resolved automatically after my next git push. For anyone experiencing this issue in future, it is probably best to give them a few days to resolve it and keep pushing good updates to your repo which will trigger their system to update the quality.